# Create buttons with radius

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create something like this on picture, but i don't have idea how to create button in html [bootstrap] with bottom-border radious?

Here is sample if what i want to create

[image]

Is it possible to create buttons like that or do something in css. 
Here is my try..

```
<div class="col-md-12">

    <a class=" col-md-6 btn btn-success btn-large btn1" href="#" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(98, 196, 98), rgb(81, 163, 81)); background-color: rgb(81, 163, 81);">Success</a>

    <a class=" col-md-6 btn btn-success btn-large btn2" href="#" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(98, 196, 98), rgb(81, 163, 81)); background-color: rgb(81, 163, 81);">Success</a>

    <div class="circle">
 <img class=" logo img-responsive" src="images/biz_club.jpg"/></div> 
    </div>

    <a class=" col-md-6 btn btn-success btn-large btn3" href="#" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(98, 196, 98), rgb(81, 163, 81)); background-color: rgb(81, 163, 81);">Success</a>

    <a class=" col-md-6 btn btn-success btn-large btn4" href="#" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(98, 196, 98), rgb(81, 163, 81)); background-color: rgb(81, 163, 81);">Success</a>
</div>
```

This look ok, but i need that border-bottom of button to be bend.

Comment: SVG would be the way to go. I'm pretty sure this is not something that you really want to do with multiple divs and CSS.

Comment: you could make 4 divs of quarter circles and position transform the text inside and then absolute the div covering them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use : `border-radius`, `overflow`, `position` and `transform`. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Kvshq)**

HTML

```
<div>
  <a href><span>Success</span></a>
  <a href><span>Success</span></a>
  <a href><span>Success</span></a>
  <a href><span>Success</span></a>
 <img  src="http://dummyimage.com/140x140/059/000&text=TEXT"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
  width:200px;
  margin:1em auto;
  position:relative;
}
a  {
  float:left;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background:gray;  
  text-align:center;
}
a span {
  display:inline-block;
  transform:rotate(-45deg);
  line-height:70px;
  color:white;
}
a+a span {/* or use a:nth-child(2) span or a ~ a span */
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
a+a+a span {
  transform:rotate(-135deg);
  line-height:125px;
}
a+a+a+a span {
  transform:rotate(135deg);
  line-height:125px;
}

a+a {/* or use a:nth-child(2) or a ~ a */
  background:lime;
}
a+a+a {
  background:purple;
}
a+a+a+a {
  background:tomato;
}
img {
  position:absolute;
  top:30px;
  left:30px;
}
div, img {
  border-radius:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow:0 0 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me buy you a beer :)